# How to get path for images objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, path, uiimageview

I want to call images from different folder, would you please help me to implement this;

I have this structure for my folders :

Folder1

```
  file1

     image1.jpg

  file2

     image2.jpg

  file3

     image3.jpg
```

Folder2 ....

inside of each file%d I have one image%.jpg

I want to call my images in loop,

```
 for (i = 1; i > image; i++)
{
    NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
```

But my question is how to enter to the folders and get images

can I have something like this :

```
 stringWithFormat:@"Folder%d/File%d/image%d" ofType:@"jpg"
```

what is the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you storing these images? In the bundle of the application? Or somewhere in Documents or Library folder?

Comment: @atxe inside of application with Library folders

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few useful code snippets that work for me.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *mapDirPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MapCache"];
```

// Creating a directory in the documents directory

```
NSError* error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:mapDirPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:mapDirPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

// loading an image

```
NSString *filePath = [self.localImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent: key];
if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    return image;
}
```

// Writing an image

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:remoteData attributes:nil];
```

Hope that helps

Of course, if you're reading images from your bundle, you want this instead
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"filename" ofType:@"png" directory: @"directory1"]

Comment: Thanks for reply , I 'm using webViewController and self.localImagePath is not the object of this class do you know what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is how I would do it.

```
for (f = 1; f <= numberOfFolders; i++) {
    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
        NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".../Folder%d/File%d/image%d.jpg", f, i, i];
        NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed: file];

        // Do something with the image
    }
}
```

A note: I don't know where Folder1/Folder2... etc are, so I used '.../' on the code. Be sure to fill that part appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate folders and images appending the image path to the library path:

```
NSString * libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

for (NSUInteger f = 1; f <= numFolders; i++) {

    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {

        // Create the image path
        NSString * imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Folder%d/File%d/image%d.jpg", libraryPath, f, i, i];

        // Check if file exists
        if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
            UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

            // Use image...
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Image not found.");
        }
    }
}
```